# Is there a way to do a For loop to a string variable and then add in each loop 6 letters to it with initial value 'A1:A',first loop 'G1:G' -javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to do a for loop with "`CantAMS = 10`" beeing the amount of loops I need and each time I loop to add 6 letters to my variables ColumnasAm, AMName, Ammail, and Check.
I have it writen now as an array of 10 X 1 and later loop through it, but I would like to create either a function or a for loop if possible where I add 6 letters to my variable each time it loops through it.

```
const CantAMS = 10
const ColumnasAm = ['A1:A', 'G1:G', 'M1:M','S1:S','Y1:Y','AE1:AE','AK1:AK','AQ1:AQ','AW1:AW','BC1:BC'];
const AMName = [ ws.getRange('A2').getValue(), ws.getRange('G2').getValue(),  ws.getRange('M2').getValue(),ws.getRange('S2').getValue(),ws.getRange('Y2').getValue(),ws.getRange('AE2').getValue(),ws.getRange('AK2').getValue(),ws.getRange('AQ2').getValue(),ws.getRange('AW2').getValue(),ws.getRange('BC2').getValue()];
const Ammail = [ ws.getRange('B2').getValue(), ws.getRange('H2').getValue(),  ws.getRange('N2').getValue(),ws.getRange('T2').getValue(),ws.getRange('Z2').getValue(), ws.getRange('AF2').getValue(),ws.getRange('AL2').getValue(),ws.getRange('AR2').getValue(),ws.getRange('AX2').getValue(),ws.getRange('BD2').getValue()];
const Check = [ ws.getRange('A5').getValue(), ws.getRange('G5').getValue(),  ws.getRange('M5').getValue(),ws.getRange('S5').getValue(),ws.getRange('Y5').getValue(),ws.getRange('AE5').getValue(),ws.getRange('AK5').getValue(),ws.getRange('AQ5').getValue(),ws.getRange('AW5').getValue(),ws.getRange('BC5').getValue()];
const Columni = [1,7,13,19,25,31,37,43,49,55];
```

Comment: Java is not JavaScript. Which language are you asking about?

Comment: srry you are right, javascript, in this case for google scripts

Comment: Could you please provide the sample of desired result?

Comment: I would like to have as an output of the for loop:
1.loop:
Cant AMs = 1
ColumnasAm  = 'A1:A'
AMName = ws.getRange('A2').getValue()
Ammail =  ws.getRange('B2').getValue()
Check =  ws.getRange('A5').getValue()
Columni = 1;
2 loop:
ColumnasAm  = 'G1:G'
AMName = ws.getRange('G2').getValue()
Ammail =  ws.getRange('H2').getValue()
Check =  ws.getRange('G5').getValue()
Columni = 7;
3 loop:
ColumnasAm  = 'M1:M'
AMName = ws.getRange('M2').getValue()
Ammail =  ws.getRange('N2').getValue()
Check =  ws.getRange('M5').getValue()
Columni = 13
...